# Loading user modules after login

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application, prism-6

The application has Login page, which is authenticated by the back-end server. Then the application can request for the user's role. Based on the role, the application need to load the modules for the user. Logout will close the application (at-least for now.).

The application uses latest version of Unity Bootstrapper, Prism-6, wpf and is desktop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: place your code what you tried so far...

Comment: found this link : http://brianlagunas.com/prism-dynamically-discover-and-load-modules-at-runtime/ and trying to customise to my need.